# Lossless crop AVCHD and save back as AVCHD

Tags: crop, h.264, lossless

I have many videos are record in **AVCHD** format by my **SONY NEX6** camera. i want to crop those useless shots and save it back to **AVCHD**. It is  because i don't want to convert to other video format which take up more space (**Apple ProRes**) than the original file, and i don't want to lower the video quality.

Is there any tools out there free or paid is fine. i just don't to to view too much rubbish shots when i play back to video ?

Comment: http://www.ffmpeg.org/ can do everything to want and more, a bit tricky to use though...

Comment: i dont see any guide doing AVCHD to AVCHD with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found TMPGEnc MPEG Smart Renderer 4 can crop my AVCHD video clips and save it back to AVCHD file to save space and without rendering

http://tmpgenc.pegasys-inc.com/en/product/tmsr4.html